# (Die) Menschen sind entspannter in St. Petersburg

Tags: grammaticality, article, grammar-identification, definite-article

Wie kann ich einer Tandempartnerin erklären, warum man im folgenden letzten Satz den Artikel "**Die**" nicht weglassen darf?

> "Die Uhren gehen in St. Petersburg etwas langsamer. ***Die*** Menschen sind entspannter."

Answer (score 5):

Der Nullartikel (damit ist das Fehlen eines Artikels gemeint) ist die Pluralform des unbestimmten Artikels:

- Bestimmt

  - Singular

    > Der Mensch ist entspannter.
  - Plural

    > Die Menschen sind entspannter.
- Unbestimmt

  - Singular

    > Ein Mensch ist entspannter.
  - Plural

    > Menschen sind entspannter.

Du redest von ganz bestimmten Menschen, nämlich von jenen in St. Petersburg. Daher ist ein bestimmter Artikel zu verwenden.

Wenn du allgemein von Menschen redest, solltest du den unbestimmten Artikel verwenden, und im Plural ist das eben der Nullartikel:

> Menschen hören weniger gut als Hunde.

Comment: Das habe ich auch gedacht, bin aber dann auf folgendes Magazin gestoßen:

[Was unterscheidet den Menschen vom Affen?](https://www.spektrum.de/news/was-unterscheidet-den-menschen-vom-affen/590105)

Hierbei handelt es sich doch auch um den unbestimmten Menschen, oder?

Comment: @masrlinu In diesem Beispiel ist _Menschen_ der Akkusativ, nicht der Plural. (Zumindest im Titel)

Comment: @masrlinu: Nein, damit ist nicht ein einzelner unbestimmter Mensch gemeint, sondern die biologische Gattung *Mensch.* Wenn man sagt *»Der Mensch ist ein Säugetier«* meint man damit, dass die Gattung *Mensch* zur Klasse *Säugetier* gehört.

Answer (score 0):

Deine Tandempartnerin hat richtig erkannt, dass es darauf ankommt, ob man eine Generalaussage trifft oder nicht.

> Uhren laufen streng im Takt. Menschen sind entspannter.

Nun ist das Beispiel

> Die Uhren gehen in St. Petersburg etwas langsamer. Die Menschen sind entspannter.

prinzipiell auch eine Generalaussage.

Allerdings über *bestimmte* langsamgehende Dinge, nämlich ***die*** Uhren, und *bestimmte* Menschen, nämlich **die** in St. Petersburg. Und schon braucht man wieder den Artikel.

Vielleicht hilft es ihr, den bestimmten Artikel als ein "kleines Demonstrativpronomen" zu sehen. Sobald man über etwas näher bestimmtes spricht, verwendet man den bestimmten Artikel.

Answer (score 0):

Bei generischen Aussagen erlaubt das Deutsche mindestens zwei Varianten.

> **Der Mensch** ist ein Mängelwesen. (definit, Singular)
> **Menschen** sind Mängelwesen. (indefinit, Plural)

Schon der Komparativ *entspannter* im Ausgangsbeispiel zeigt, daß keine generische Aussage vorliegt: Es geht um die Menschen in St. Petersburg im Vergleich zu anderen.

Außerhalb generischer Aussagen wird der definite Artikel benutzt, um auf schon eingeführte Größen Bezug zu nehmen. Im einfachsten Fall werden neue Größen durch eine indefinite Nominalphrase eingeführt; sie können aber auch aus anderen erschlossen werden.

> Die Firma stellte **ein neues Smartphone** vor. **Das Gerät** verfügt über einen faltbaren Bildschirm.
>
> Du kannst mein Auto nehmen. **Die Schlüssel** liegen auf dem Tisch.

Im zweiten Beispiel setzt der Sprecher voraus, daß mit der Erwähnung des Autos auch die dazugehörigen Schlüssel schon eingeführt sind. Ähnlich beim Ausgangsbeispiel: Mit der Erwähnung der Stadt St. Petersburg gelten auch die Bewohner der Stadt als eingeführt, so daß der bestimmte Artikel verwendet werden muß. Indefinites *Menschen* würde dagegen als generisch interpretiert.