# viele oder viel for Verwandte

Tags: german-to-english, standard-german

### i saw in A2 book they write viele Verwandte ?

Der Verwandte und in plural we have Die Verwandten
why we write Viele verwandte

regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50536/die-menschen-sind-entspannter-in-st-petersburg

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/64630/what-type-of-declension-is-used-for-the-nouns-deutsche-and-verwandte, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/34826/strong-weak-declension-of-adjectives-with-alle-and-viele, https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/25357/same-noun-same-case-same-adjective-different-ending-what-are-the-rules-behi.

Comment: Is your question about "die Verwandte**n**" vs. "viele Verwandte" or about "viel" vs "viel**e**"?

Answer (score 1):

1. Some nouns inflect like adjectives.

> ein Deutsch**er**, der Deutsch**e**
> ein Verwandt**er**, der Verwandt**e**
>
> ein deutsch**er** Kollege, der deutsch**e** Kollege
> ein verwandt**er** Vorschlag, der verwandt**e** Vorschlag

2. As the previous examples show, adjectives have two different sets of endings depending on whether a determiner with an ending (such as *der*) is present or not (*ein* does not have an ending). In the plural:

> gut**e** Vorschläge
> die best**en** Vorschläge

3. *Alle* is a determiner, whereas *viele* is an adjective.

> alle deutsch**en** Kollegen
>
> viel**e** deutsch**e** Kollegen
> unsere viel**en** deutsch**en** Kollegen

Answer (score 1):

> why we write Viele verwandte

For the same reason we write *many* in English, instead of *much*. When you talk about something countable (your relatives are persons - "units" you can count) you use "viele" (many), when talking about amounts (like with water) you use "viel" (much).

Compare the following two:

> Water - *much* water - *viel* Wasser
> buckets of water - *many* buckets of water - *viele* Eimer Wasser

As long as we talk about the water itself, it is an (amorphous) *amount*, once we have units - buckets - these units become a (countable) *number* of items. In the former case we use "much" and "viel", in the latter we use "many" and "viele".

Notice, that there are some fringe cases:

> viele Wasser (many waters)

This is not about some *amount* of water but *sorts* of water - these are actually countable again, hence "viele".

Comment: @Olafant: because with water the distinction between countable units and uncountable amounts was possible to show and also "many waters" (in the sense of "sorts of water") could be explained. All things not possible with relatives.

Comment: It answers the question "why we write Viele verwandte" in the way that explains why one uses the (capitalized - hence I took it as the core of the question) "viele" instead of "viel". What exactly do you want from me?

Comment: I read it again and realized my mistake. Sorry.